# how to add an embedded titlebar to webview on android 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, android-webview

In my project I neet to add an embedded titlebar to the WebView. then the titlebar can scroll with the WebView. before kitkat it works fine. the implements code I refs com.google.android.browser which is public in AOSP. but android kitkat the open source browser's titlebar can not scrolled with the WebView. but the Chrome browser it works. anyone how to implements it on Kitkat?

Answer (score 1):

The pre-KK Browser titlebar implementation you're referring to used hidden APIs which are no longer supported in the KitKat WebView. It's hard to say what the workaround should be - maybe try reimplementing the titlebar using fixed-position HTML?